# php's mysqli::commit has a $name param - what does it do

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

> `public mysqli::commit(int $flags = 0, ?string $name = null): bool`
>
> **Parameters**
> **flags**:  A bitmask of MYSQLI_TRANS_COR_* constants.
> **name**:  If provided then `COMMIT/*name*/` is executed.

My question:  what is `COMMIT/*name*/` ??

I can't find any Mysql documentation for this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html

nor any usage in the wild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So  I turned on query logging

and this is what was logged

**passing name to commit():**

```
Query   START TRANSACTION
Query   INSERT INTO `bob` (`t`) VALUES ("test 1")
Query   SAVEPOINT `foo`
Query   INSERT INTO `bob` (`t`) VALUES ("test 2")
Query   COMMIT /*foo*/
```

both queries were logged

**passing name to rollback:**

```
Query   START TRANSACTION
Query   INSERT INTO `bob` (`t`) VALUES ("test 1")
Query   SAVEPOINT `foo`
Query   INSERT INTO `bob` (`t`) VALUES ("test 2")
Query   ROLLBACK /*foo*/
Query   COMMIT /*comment*/
```

neither insert happened... entire transaction was rolled back

**Nutshell**:

`mysqli::commit` and `mysqli::rollback` have $name parameters that don't do anything beside add a comment to the query.

To actually rollback to a savepoint, you'll have to execute a query (ROLLBACK TO `name`).

mysqli extension provides a `savepoint($name)` method, but no rollback_to_savepoint!

Comment: https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/1588

Answer (score 1):

When you [start a transaction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php), you have the option of creating a [savepoint name](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html) for the transaction. You can then use that name to commit. From the MySQL docs:

> The SAVEPOINT statement sets a named transaction savepoint with a name of identifier. If the current transaction has a savepoint with the same name, the old savepoint is deleted and a new one is set.

Comment: What is bothering me that COMMIT doesn't accept any parameters, does it? And in the mysqli doc the name is taken in comments. So I suppose it is not a savepoint name but just a comment for the log. I am not 100% sure tho

Comment: @YourCommonSense  to add to my confusion.   php's documentation for rollback has the same syntax:  "If provided then ROLLBACK/*name*/ is executed."

Comment: @BradKent then it means I am wrong because you CAN rollack to savepoint

Comment: I'm not sure why the name is in comments. That bears some investigation. There's also [public mysqli::savepoint(string $name): bool](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.savepoint.php), so you can set save points in the transaction

Comment: @aynber I think I got it. It's mysql way to support new features. a version that knows about savepoints will use the name from the comments. Otherwise it will just ignore the comment without errors

Comment: But I can't find any Mysql documentation for committing to a savepoint...

Comment: @BradKent I linked that under savepoint name, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/savepoint.html

Comment: @BradKent as far as I understand, you don't commit to savepoint. savepoint itself IS the commit to savepoint. when you commit, you commit the entire transaction. Dunno why there is a name. may be for compatibility

Comment: @YourCommonSense.    apparently if you want to rollback to a savepoint, you'll have to do it via a query, because `mysqli::rollback(0, 'name');` doesn't do it..   https://stackoverflow.com/a/72310535/1371433